# File search in csv in uipath

Tags: csv, search, uipath

I'm trying to figure out a way to search in a google csv (list of names) if a name is present.

Is it possible in uipath?

According to my research, it may fall into the web recorder and the use the module to read csv?

Here is what I tried again:

1. In the main screen, I created a sequence.
2. Open a browser to a url like this
   "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xyzz/edit#gid=0"
3. Added a "Navigate to" the above URL again.
4. Then selected "Data Scraping".
5. Click on the first row of google sheet.
6. Then to create a pattern I clicked on next row. It couldn't find a pattern.

So I'm stuck on the final 6th position. I tried downloading and working on the csv as an alternative. But I would rather want it on the google sheet in the browser.

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: What is a Google CSV - do you mean a Google Sheet? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, It for a Google Sheet. I will update the question with my trails so far.

Comment: What do you need the Google Sheet for? Is it going to be still the same sheet or different each time? Are you developing within a business environment or personal?

Comment: Yes @MarekStejskal. It's going to be one same sheet everytime. I'm new to UiPath and was trying on automating these sequence of steps when I came across a video on youtube.

Comment: Are you comfortable with REST web services?

Comment: @marek Yes I'm. Is there any way?

Comment: @jim I'm gonna try that. Thanks!

Comment: You should definitely try using Google Sheets API before trying OCR. Answer from @Konstantinos seems like a best solution. Otherwise look at the REST API https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is:

1. to download Google GSuite set of activities from [Google GSuite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NAIk.png).
   *Place it under Packages folder in your UiPath installation folder and load it via Manage Packages option in Design Mode.*
2. Use ***GSuite Application Scope*** (you need to fill your ClientID and ClientSecret for your account)
3. Use activity ***Find Files and Folders*** to search for the file that you want by name. You will get the file ID (in your case the SpreadSheetID) as output
4. Use a Read ***Range activity*** placing the output from step 3 to get the contents of spreadsheet as DataTable
5. Use your pattern to search through DataTable for the desired result.

Activities are shown as per below (Highlighted are the ones to use)-(Notification on the second Image is due to the fact that ClientID and ClientSecret are mandatory and i left them empty):

[image]

[image]

Hope you will find these information useful

Comment: I'm gonna try your solution. Looks like it should do the trick. Thanks! I will update it by EOD tomorrow.